# Scrollview not scrolling, after I set the content size and tested that it changed

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have this hierarchy:

View controller --> Scroll view --> view --> some labels 
My view is (inside the scroll view) is hidden when keyboard is opened, so I used a scroll view to overcome that problem.

I connected my scroll view as an outlet to my View controller, set the content size and activated the scroll. It still does not scroll. This is my view controller code:

```
import UIKit

class EditViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var editScroll: UIScrollView!

@IBAction func backButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    editScroll.isScrollEnabled = true
    editScroll.contentSize = (editScroll.superview?.bounds.size)!
    print(editScroll.contentSize) // this prints the correct numbers!

}



}
```

Comment: The frames may not be calculated yet in ```viewDidLoad```. Try this code in ```viewDidAppear``` or even better:```viewDidLayoutSubviews```. EDIT: I added that as an answer for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. You are a genius, why comment and not answer this? I will accept it as an answer if you would

Comment: Also if you want a plug-and-play third party library to handle the keyboard offset, I suggest : https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager. Not good for every use, but saves a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frames may not be calculated yet in `viewDidLoad`. Put your code in `viewDidAppear` or even better: `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get screen size, just use this:

```
UIScreen.main.bounds.size
```

and there is a open source about keyboard hide and show's problem.

maybe can use this one to resolve it.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager